# Why do I get these warnings/errors when I clone this project from my team on Github. It's only on my machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, github, asp.net-core-3.0

[image: Error image]

I cloned the project from my teammates, they don't get this error but I do. Why and how can I fix this?

Comment: Have a look into your Nuget setup and diff with your teammates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to install .NET Core 3.0? Those package warnings are saying there's packages that are incompatible with your project. The project target framework for the packages raising the warnings is .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0

Answer (score 1):

Have occurred to me when I started using Android studio on my Macbook. I have upgraded my gradle to the latest version and rebuilt my project. Basically, you have to update and install all the system environments used to run the project.